# how to resolve "socket hang up" error. NestJS + socket.io

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

Thank you for reading this question.

I want to make a socket.io server using NestJS. and debugging the server set up localhost, I get the folloring error.

```
$ wscat -c ws://localhost:80
error: socket hang up
```

mock.gateway.ts

```js
import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, MessageBody, ConnectedSocket, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

import { MockEventName } from '@shared/events';
import { ServerToClient, ClientToServer } from '@shared/connection';

@WebSocketGateway({
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    },
})
export class MockGateway {
    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server = new Server<ServerToClient, ClientToServer>();

    @SubscribeMessage(MockEventName)
    mock(
        @MessageBody() data: string,
        @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket
    ): void {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit(MockEventName, { message: 'response' });
    }
}
```

MockGateway is provided to InterfaceModule, and it is imported by AppModule.

main.ts

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(80);
}
bootstrap();
```

There are no wrong I can't find in gateways.
I think is a mistake on decorator settings. If anyone has any ideas, please comment.

Comment: this question has changed premise, so I re-posted another question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75211028/how-to-resolve-socket-io-error-transporterror-xhr-poll-error). Sorry to the admin team, but we would appreciate it if you could close it.