# How to resolve socket.io Error "TransportError: xhr poll error"

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I want to make a socket.io server using NestJS.
I'm trying communication between server and client on localhost.
however, client(socket.io-client) throw the following error.

```
TransportError: xhr poll error
```

the server was running on localhost:3000. and the client was run from node command(node index.js)

server (mock.gateway.ts)

```js
import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, MessageBody, ConnectedSocket, WebSocketServer} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class MockGateway {
    @WebSocketServer()
    server;

    @SubscribeMessage('mock')
    mock(
        @MessageBody() data: string,
        @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket
    ): void {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

server (main.ts)

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

client

```js
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('ws://localhost:3000', {
    path: '/socket.io',
});
socket.emit('mock', 'mock');
```

I tried set transports to the sockect.io-client. but it makes a timeout error.

```js
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('ws://localhost:3000', {
    path: '/socket.io',
    transports: ['websocket'],
});
socket.emit('mock', 'mock');
```

Maybe a mistake in module settings. so I use the wscat is debug-tool. It throws the following error, I'm wondering why wscat can connest Nest server.

```
$ wscat -c ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/\?transport=websocket
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
error: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear
```

If anyone has any ideas, please comment.

Comment: wscat(and executed client by node command) was not able to established. but I can established executed client by browser.